# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nz}$ is analytic in the right half plane $\text{Re}(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nz}$$
Using Weierstrass theorem, prove that the series is analytic in $\text{Re}(z)>0$.

I know that $f$ is analytic if it satisfies Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Could someone refer me to this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\{z\in \mathbb C \ | \ \text{Re}(z)>0\}$.

Then, there exist $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $0<a\leq b$ and $K\subset \{z\in \mathbb C \ | \ a\leq \text{Re}(z)\leq b\}$.

Observe that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{-nz}$ converges uniformaly on $K$.